# how to refresh search result Web Part (OOTB)?

Tags: development, search-results, ootb

[image: Currently using Search OOTB ,in search Box enter some text and click on search button it display result ,but after that i clear the text in search box and click on search button ,the search web part not getting refresh , how to refresh search result Web Part (OOTB)]

Currently  using Search OOTB ,in search Box enter some text and click on search button it display result ,but after that i clear the text in search box and click on search button ,the search web part not getting refresh , how to refresh search result Web Part (OOTB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all calls on the 2013 search page is done using AJAX, the real query is added to the hash part of the url, the part coming after the # character. If you want to clear all filters and the search terms, then you can add what designers call a dummy link with a # to the page, and that will reset your query.

Ref Link :  http://techmikael.blogspot.in/2013/06/add-clear-filters-link-to-your-search.html

Comment: is there any OOTB Feature(OOTB Control)available?(means any by default feature for search result webpart,to refresh)...        client don't want to use Content Editor,Ajax,JavaScript,JSon..

Comment: Clients Want to use By Default Functionality for refresh,,Is It Possible ,**IT'S Urgent**

Comment: there is know OOB configuration for search result webpart to clear the search results when it's empty.

Comment: go through this technet post it helps to show your client..      http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/11/06/how-to-configure-the-search-results-web-part-to-use-a-new-result-source-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx    #darsh and bella had similar issue..